# Self Documenting REST Services in ASP .NET Core 2.0

Tags: c#, .net, rest, swagger, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to publish REST metadata for a REST API that our services serve up. ASP.Net has changed so many times over the last few years, I can't get any useful information on what the recommended practice is right now. The name that keeps coming up is Swagger. ***I'm guessing that this is the recommended framework these days. Is that a safe assumption?***

But, in order to use Swagger, we need to use open source libraries that bolt on to ASP.NET Core 2.0. It doesn't seem that Swagger support is built in to ASP.NET Core 2.0. I figure that Microsoft must have some kind of standard out of the box self documentation for REST services, but I can't find any documentation on it. ***Is there something built in to ASP.NET Core 2.0 for self documenting REST Services?*** If so, ***is it worth trying to implement it instead of Swagger? Or, is Swagger just that superior?***

***Is there a de facto standard .NET Swagger library for ASP.NET Core 2.0***? This article seems to recommend Swashbuckle. ***Is Swashbuckle a safe bet?***

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/web-api-help-pages-using-swagger?tabs=visual-studio

Comment: I'd say use Swagger, use Swashbuckle, don't reinvent the wheel.

Comment: As an FYI, Microsoft is recommending lots of third-party packages/frameworks/tools lately, so don't be too surprised (they even removed their own `JavaScriptSerializer` in favor of `NewtonSoft.Json`'s)

Answer (score 4):

ASP.NET Core 2.0 doesn't have a built-in API documentation generator. Swagger is the most common (probably the best) API documentation framework you're likely to find. Swashbuckle is not a replacement for Swagger, but rather a mechanism for generating swagger-compatible metadata from the XML documentation that you write into your code.

[Here's](https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle.AspNetCore) where you'll probably want to start.

Comment: Everything on the web seems to agree with this answer but I'm still unable to get Swashbuckle working. I've followed several blog posts etc. but they all recommend different methods for configuring it. Some compile. Some don't, but nothing works. I will try the link you have provided to see if it takes me any further.

Comment: I was looking at this example: https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples . It does work, but I can't figure out how to get it in working in my services. I've followed his instructions but nothing works

Comment: I've got the Json endpoint working, but but I can't figure out how to hit the UI index. None of the articles specify what the default Url should be for the UI index page. My guess is that it should be swagger/ui/index but that just returns nothing.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper I'm not sure what you mean by the "UI Index", but have you tried `/swagger` and `/swagger/docs/v1`?

Comment: I ended up getting this working, and yes that is what I ended up with in the end. @StriplingWarrior, a comprehensive article needs to be written up on this. I found that several articles on this are misleading, including the one you posted. They tell some of the story, but not all. For example, there were several NuGet packages I had to add, to get it to work. I'm considering writing a blog post myself. But, if you want to beef out your answer to include all the steps from start to finish, I will mark your response as the answer.

Comment: Another issue now, is to further beef out the documentation with examples etc. Again, the documentation is floating around, but it's all piecemeal. There's no one article which tells you all the main stuff you need to know - and the example I did find, is for an older version of ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @MelbourneDeveloper: Another option is to write your own answer and accept it.

Comment: Yes. I will probably do that. But, actually, the answer is too involved for a simple answer here. I need to write a full blog post. Hopefully, I'll get around to that over the weekend. But, what you've posted led me to the answers that allowed me to get over the hump.

Comment: This library serves up swagger examples: https://github.com/mattfrear/Swashbuckle.Examples , but this doesn't work in ASP .Net Core 2.0 which is what led me astray. And, I don't really see any way to implement the same thing in ASP.NET Core 2.0